# Facebook sharer's cache on my site

Tags: facebook, facebook-sharer

I have problem with Facebook Sharer.
I've created a simple share button to include page on Facebook's wall, but the title, description and image are wrong.

I've cleared cache with debug tool but on my site the button show me old elements. How can I refresh it?

Comment: Try to change the url with a custom get parameter. Append this to your url `?v=1.1`.

Comment: Did you clear your browser cache on your end?

Comment: My url is already with get parameters and my cache is clear! I don't know why doesn't works!

The url is like this:
http://www.site.com/aff/frame.php?banner=1&aff=1
Where `banner` is the id of the image utilized for share on facebook and `aff` is for track click on the link.